# For some reason wget downloads an 8 byte file instead of the original

Tags: linux, shell, centos, download, wget

Downloading this specific file `http://www5.mp4upload.com:182/d/skxswmshz3b4quuof6ue2kskcg2hdh7otrmeb56mjbszssvgh22btuy6/video.mp4`

using `wget` like so

`wget http://www5.mp4upload.com:182/d/skxswmshz3b4quuof6ue2kskcg2hdh7otrmeb56mjbszssvgh22btuy6/video.mp4`

Seems to only download an 8 byte file, while using this link in your browser correctly grabs and downloads the whole file. What is the issue in this case?

Comment: Is it possible that the server is streaming the mp4 file?

Comment: that server is indeed streaming the mp4file.

Comment: When I fetch the URL using 'wget', I get an 8-byte as well-- and those 8 bytes consist of the characters "Wrong IP". I get the same thing when I visit from Chrome or Firefox, both on Windows. What browser works for you?

Comment: @MultimediaMike it's going to work in my browser because I generated the link from that IP. However, it shouldn't work for anyone else, because we don't have the same IP. My question is how can I generate that link using `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: Did you write the nginx rule that decides wrong IP?